# Running a local installation of Karma with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

Due to a few limitations on the build machine I need to ideally use a local installation of karma. I can see that the tests will complete when I run.

```
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
```

However I now need to try and run the tests using Grunt. Is there anyway using grunt-karma or similar to specify the karma path? (i.e. Not use the global command as it will not be installed)

Answer (score 0):

On this page: https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma

You can find this example:

```
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
  }
}
```

With this (and the related module) you can trigger karma tasks from grunt.